# Why does the sum() window function require order by, when it has "between unbounded preceding and unbounded following"?

Tags: sql, sum, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

I got an error today attempting something like

```
sum(balance) over(rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
```

The error was that the window requires an order by statement. But, when summing over all rows (which gives the same result as simply sum(balance) without a window function), the order by information is not necessary. Not only that, I don't want SQL to waste time ordering my rows just to sum them all.

Is there a good reason that SQL requires order by in this case? Am I naive, have I missed something, or is this actually unnecessary?

Comment: How would you otherwise determine what is before (preceding) or after (following) without some kind of `order`?

Comment: It requires an order by statement when you specify a window frame. Just do `sum over()`

Comment: If you want to sum them all, then use `over()` without anything inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to compute over entire window, there is no need to provide  `ORDER BY` and window frame:

```
SELECT SUM(balance) OVER(PARTITION BY col)
FROM tab

SELECT SUM(balance) OVER()
FROM tab
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems like the best way to write it. I'm getting used to the fact that `OVER()` on its own has an implicit `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`, while `OVER(ORDER BY column_name)`  has an implicit `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` instead. I wonder if those are both general rules.

Comment: @doublefelix As for OVER(ORDER BY col_name)  it is described in the doc [Window Frame Usage Notes](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic.html#window-frame-usage-notes)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Snowflake, could see that your `unbounded preceding` and `unbounded following` makes it the same as `SUM(balance)` and thus rewrite it for you, like many other DBs,

*OR* you could learn to ask for what you want and not write poor SQL and then have the DB have to auto-magic-clean-up for every time that and every other piece of SQL is run.

Comment: You didn't know the use case so your criticism is misdirected. Within context, there is a reason I didn't just use sum() without a window function, namely that is not the granularity that this table should have. Not only that, but this doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @doublefelix You are correct I cannot read your mind, and understand the unstated details that you left out because "they do not add material value", albeit you want to point at the existence of unstated facts. I stand by "you problem as stated seems wrong", I notice you have not edited your question to add those details that make the question make sense.